Node JS API not run in physical device but run successfully in AVD, How I fix it?
I make a simple API using Node JS to collect data from firebase database and the API connect with my Flutter App to take data from API because when I add cloud_firestore package in Flutter application, app getting error so I build the API. But here, my Node.js API runs successfully in the Android Virtual Device (AVD) but encounters errors when running on a physical device, why? how I fix it?
API Code:
const WebSocket = require('ws');

// Create a WebSocket server
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

// Handle WebSocket connections
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  console.log('Client connected');

  // Send a welcome message to the client
  ws.send('Welcome to the WebSocket server!');

  // Handle messages from the client
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    if (typeof message === 'string') {
      console.log('Received message from client:', message);

      // Echo the message back to the client
      ws.send('Server says: ' + message);
    } else if (message instanceof Buffer) {
      // If message is a Buffer, convert it to a string
      const strMessage = message.toString('utf-8');
      console.log('Received binary message from client:', strMessage);

      // Echo the message back to the client
      ws.send('Server says: ' + strMessage);
    } else {
      console.log('Unknown message format received from client');
    }
  });

  // Handle disconnection
  ws.on('close', function close() {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
});

Flutter Code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {   @override  
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState(); }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {   final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();   final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://10.0.2.2:8080');

  String _data = '';

  @override   void dispose() {
    _textController.dispose();
    channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();   }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_textController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      channel.sink.add(_textController.text);
      _textController.clear();
    }   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebSocket Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: channel.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              }
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                _data = snapshot.data;
              }
              return Center(child: Text('Data from WebSocket: $_data'));
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _textController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Send Message',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _sendMessage,
                  child: Text('Send'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );   } }

error:

